# Which update to Team Fortress 2 added cosmetics and the inventory?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Around 2008, Team Fortress 2 had the addition of cosmetic items, and an inventory. Previously, you unlocked weapons via completing milestones.

What was the last game version before this major update?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that TF2 is a steam game, so that would require the latest version of the game to be ran to play online. Also, unless someone uploaded a cracked installer/zip file (cracked as in skips steam client verification) on the interwebs, you won't be able to play the old version.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a game recommendation. Your asking "which version", not "which game". I think I have a solution that retains your intent, but feel free to roll it back, or let me know, if your unable to do so. Remember, asking for a source to play the game is like asking for a recommendation. You might be able to ask "would it be legally possible to play this version", in which you would get a better answer of "only if valve actually put it back up".

Comment: As @user3878893 states, this is primarily a steam game. However, **I am positive Team Fortress 2 was available on Xbox 360 and PS3**. I wonder if these versions have the same version?

Comment: @Timelord64 I did some more browsing around and people are currently playing 1.0.0.9 (a.k.a. The Orange Box CD version or 360/PS3 version) with servers up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmetics and the weapon drop system were added to the game in the [Sniper vs. Spy update](http://www.teamfortress.com/sniper_vs_spy/).

However, due to complaints, milestone rewards for Sniper and Spy weapons were added in a [week later](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/May_29,_2009_Patch) and were kept for the [WAR Update](http://www.teamfortress.com/war/) (aka the Demo vs. Soldier update) and [Engineer Update](http://www.teamfortress.com/engineerupdate/).

No new weapons have been awarded as achievement items since the Engineer update.

[Crafting](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting) was introduced to TF2 in the WAR Update in late 2009.

These days, you have to either wait until you get a new weapon as a drop, trade for said item with another player, or craft it using the crafting system.

If you want to know what items you need to craft an item, you can check the [Crafting Wiki page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting) or check the crafting recipes in the game's Crafting interface.

To access the Crafting screen, first click the Items button:

[image: Items button]

then the Crafting button

[image: Crafting button]

In the Crafting system, weapons are considered Common items, which are accessed by clicking on the button that look like a Pie Chart

[image: Common Items button]

Finally, click on an item to see what it requires

[image: Crit-a-Cola requirements]

Clicking on the names of the names of the item it requires will bring up a special inventory screen to look for valid items.

Answer (score 2):

Team Fortress 2 still allows you to unlock weapons via milestones; the only thing that really changed was the introduction of the item drop system that brought in other weapons.

As read here from the [TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Achievement_items#Milestone_achievements):

> **Each class can earn three Milestone achievements**. Milestone
>   achievements are awarded for earning 5, 11, and 17 achievements in a
>   class; or 10, 16, and 22 achievements in a class; depending on the
>   class. Each Milestone achievement counts towards future Milestone
>   achievements.
>
> The following classes earn Milestone achievements at 5, 11, and 17
>   class achievements:
>
> - Soldier
> - Demoman
> - Engineer
> - Sniper
> - Spy
>
> The following classes earn Milestone achievements at 10, 16, and 22
>   class achievements:
>
> - Scout
> - Pyro
> - Heavy
> - Medic

The rest of the link shows the "milestone weapons" rewarded at each tier.